# Show list of directories in path php & htm

Tags: php, html

I would like to show a list of all subdirectories in the directory on the UI Interface using php .The directories will show up as a button and the user can select which directory.

Here is my code so far

```
$path = /path;
$dir = glob($path.'/*/,GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Please how do I go about this? Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: It currently shows the whole path name.How can I show just the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreach to loop through the results of glob function. Example:

```
$path = '/';
$dirs = glob($path.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

foreach($dirs as $dir) {
    echo '<a href="?dir='.$dir.'">'.$dir.'</a><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looping the array and printing each directory:

```
foreach ($dir as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

Depending on how you want to add that to your UI, you can dress that up with a button code:

```
echo "<button>$item</button>";
```

Then you could add some javascript to add an action to whatever should happen when the user clicks that button.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This works.But it currently shows the whole path name.How can I show just the name?

Comment: There are many ways, here is one: explode("/", $item) and then get the last element with array_pop